# amp-bind-macro causes validation to fail

Tags: amp-html

I can't get amp-bind-macro to work, not even the example provided at https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind#defining-macros-with-amp-bind-macro.

Whenever I add an amp-bind-macro tag I get the following error during validation: "The tag 'amp-bind-macro' is disallowed."

Here's the source I'm using:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://ampbyexample.com/introduction/hello_world/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
</head>
<body>
    <amp-state id="myCircle">
        <script type="application/json">
            {
                "radius": 0
            }
        </script>
    </amp-state>
    <amp-bind-macro name="circleArea" arguments="radius" expression="3.14 * radius * radius" />
    <div>
      The circle has an area of <span [text]="circleArea(myCircle.radius)">0</span>.
    </div>
    <button on="tap:AMP.setState({myCircle: {radius: 10}})">
        Set to 10
    </button>
    <button on="tap:AMP.setState({myCircle: {radius: 20}})">
        Set to 20
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the log when running in development mode:

> Navigated to http://localhost:8002/macro-test.html viewer-impl.js:707
>   Powered by AMP ? HTML – Version 1515614886756
>   http://localhost:8002/macro-test.html#development=1
>   content_script.js:24 initializing Content Script message listener
>   validator.js:426 AMP validation had errors: lx.error @
>   validator.js:426 (anonymous) @ validator.js:441 e.b @ validator.js:365
>   bu @ validator.js:368 Xt @ validator.js:368 Ot.j @ validator.js:368 Nt
>   @ validator.js:362 Promise resolved (async) Kt @ validator.js:362 Jt @
>   validator.js:362 Zt @ validator.js:367 Pt @ validator.js:367
>   (anonymous) @ validator.js:362 d.onreadystatechange @ validator.js:440
>   XMLHttpRequest.send (async) (anonymous) @ validator.js:440 Ot @
>   validator.js:362 sx @ validator.js:440 (anonymous) @ validator.js:441
>   (anonymous) @ viewer-impl.js:547 Promise resolved (async) yl @
>   viewer-impl.js:547 h @ viewer-impl.js:702 Of @
>   url-replacements-impl.js:833 Kf.He @ url-replacements-impl.js:994
>   (anonymous) @ url-replacements-impl.js:1007 Promise resolved (async)
>   Qf @ url-replacements-impl.js:59 Kf.Na @ url-replacements-impl.js:1024
>   (anonymous) @ url-replacements-impl.js:963 Promise resolved (async) Mf
>   @ url-replacements-impl.js:960 Jf @ url-replacements-impl.js:827
>   (anonymous) @ viewer-impl.js:674 Id @ bytes.js:84 initial @
>   viewer-impl.js:589 Of @ url-replacements-impl.js:833 Kf.He @
>   url-replacements-impl.js:994 (anonymous) @
>   url-replacements-impl.js:1007 Promise resolved (async) Qf @
>   url-replacements-impl.js:59 Kf.Na @ url-replacements-impl.js:1024
>   (anonymous) @ url-replacements-impl.js:963 Promise resolved (async) Mf
>   @ url-replacements-impl.js:960 Jf @ url-replacements-impl.js:827
>   (anonymous) @ viewer-impl.js:547 (anonymous) @ viewer-impl.js:743
>   validator.js:426 http://localhost:8002/macro-test.html:25:4 The tag
>   'amp-bind-macro' is disallowed. lx.error @ validator.js:426
>   (anonymous) @ validator.js:442 e.b @ validator.js:365 bu @
>   validator.js:368 Xt @ validator.js:368 Ot.j @ validator.js:368 Nt @
>   validator.js:362 Promise resolved (async) Kt @ validator.js:362 Jt @
>   validator.js:362 Zt @ validator.js:367 Pt @ validator.js:367
>   (anonymous) @ validator.js:362 d.onreadystatechange @ validator.js:440
>   XMLHttpRequest.send (async) (anonymous) @ validator.js:440 Ot @
>   validator.js:362 sx @ validator.js:440 (anonymous) @ validator.js:441
>   (anonymous) @ viewer-impl.js:547 Promise resolved (async) yl @
>   viewer-impl.js:547 h @ viewer-impl.js:702 Of @
>   url-replacements-impl.js:833 Kf.He @ url-replacements-impl.js:994
>   (anonymous) @ url-replacements-impl.js:1007 Promise resolved (async)
>   Qf @ url-replacements-impl.js:59 Kf.Na @ url-replacements-impl.js:1024
>   (anonymous) @ url-replacements-impl.js:963 Promise resolved (async) Mf
>   @ url-replacements-impl.js:960 Jf @ url-replacements-impl.js:827
>   (anonymous) @ viewer-impl.js:674 Id @ bytes.js:84 initial @
>   viewer-impl.js:589 Of @ url-replacements-impl.js:833 Kf.He @
>   url-replacements-impl.js:994 (anonymous) @
>   url-replacements-impl.js:1007 Promise resolved (async) Qf @
>   url-replacements-impl.js:59 Kf.Na @ url-replacements-impl.js:1024
>   (anonymous) @ url-replacements-impl.js:963 Promise resolved (async) Mf
>   @ url-replacements-impl.js:960 Jf @ url-replacements-impl.js:827
>   (anonymous) @ viewer-impl.js:547 (anonymous) @ viewer-impl.js:743
>   validator.js:443 See also
>   https://validator.ampproject.org/#url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8002%2Fmacro-test.html
>   error.js:188 amp-bind: Expression evaluation error in
>   "circleArea(myCircle.radius)". circleArea is not a supported
>   function.???

Comment: Can you provide the logs when you have tested the sample [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind#defining-macros-with-amp-bind-macro)?

Comment: Sure, I'll provide the full page source as well in the original question.

Comment: I can see a new rule for the validator in https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-bind/validator-amp-bind.protoascii but usually the validator takes a bit to be deployed. If you still see this issue in a week, I suggest to open an issue on github.

Comment: Solved it! amp-bind-macro tags should have an "id" attribute instead of "name". Must have been a typo in the official documentation, they've updated it now.